# Error file not exists even though file is present when passing filename as args in spark-submit

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am passing config filename as args in spark2-submit. But i am getting file not exists error even though the file exists. If i hard-code the file name, it is working fine.

```
 spark2-submit --files /data/app/Data_validation/target/input.conf --class "QualityCheck" DC_framework-jar-with-dependencies.jar "input.conf"
```

code:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkFiles

object QualityCheck {
    def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit={
        val configFile = SparkFiles.get("input.conf")
        val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Check Global")
        val sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf)
        val spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

        println(configFile)
        if (file.exists) {
          val config = ConfigFactory.parseFile(file)
        } else {
        println("Configuration file does not exist")
```

Stacktrace:

```
/data/app/Data_validation/target/input.conf
Configuration file does not exist
Config(SimpleConfigObject({}))
```

please help!

Comment: are you running in local more or cluster mode ??

Comment: Cluster mode. If i hard-code the same path, its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code.

```
spark2-submit --class "QualityCheck" DC_framework-jar-with-dependencies.jar "/data/app/Data_validation/target/input.conf"

object QualityCheck {
    def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit={

        val file = new File(args(0))
        if (file.exists) {
          val config = ConfigFactory.parseFile(file)
        } else {
        println("Configuration file does not exist")
        }

        val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Check Global")
        val sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf)
        val spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tested with above option, is it working ??

Comment: Is it failed again ??

Comment: Yes, inside you have add this line - SparkFiles.get("filename")

Comment: Its not working as expected. I am getting below message '`tmp/spark-d01ab9bc-21fa-46d5-99a8-dab098bb60ae/userFiles-6eeec0aa-f69b-4ca2-a8ab-248d66e62189/input.conf
Configuration file does not exist`

Comment: Can you post full code .. are you loading config after spark session initiated ??

Comment: Try moving your config related code to above spark session and just use filename

Comment: One last .. Check code now, I have updated & spark2-submit command & code.

Comment: Sorry. No luck. It is picking the argument value, but it is still failing

Comment: can you post full stack trace if possible ??

Comment: I have added the stack trace. But there is no error. Just getting file not exists message

Comment: are you executing same code which is in question ??

Comment: is file available in that location, can you execute ls -ltr & show output

Comment: Yes. The file exists in the folder. If i hard-code the same path, it is working fine. Sorry not able to upload images from my office laptop